# Add an element at the beginning of an array and shift the rest but keep the size

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I need to create a vector/array in the following format:

```
arr[10] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10]
```

I want to add a new element at the beginning after which all elements are shifted to the right and the last element is deleted. The result should be:

```
arr[10] = [new_int, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

How can I do this in c++? Do I have to write a function or there is already an existing one like .append or .pushback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's an `std::vector`, the trivial solution is:

```
vec.pop_back();
vec.insert(vec.begin(), new_int);
```

The asymptotic complexity is the same as any other method to accomplish this (`pop_back()` is O(1), `insert` in head is O(n), no reallocation is ever performed) but it temporarily touches the vector length for no good reason and does overall more bookkeeping.

A better solution (that is fine both for `std::vector`, `std::array` as well as for C-style array) is:

```
std::copy_backward(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec)-1, std::begin(vec)+1);
vec[0] = new_int;
```

This, again, should have O(n) complexity, but a smaller "offset" (it does exactly what it needs to do, nothing more).

---

Now, if we move to different data structures the situation is different; with an `std::deque` you can do as *@JesperJuhl* shows in his answer; pushing/popping at both ends of a `deque` costs amortized O(1), so it's reasonably fast for most uses.

Still, if your buffer is fixed in size, generally the natural data structure for the operation you describe is the fixed-size circular buffer; it is not provided by the standard library, but there's an implementation in Boost (besides, it's also a nice exercise to write it yourself, with iterators and everything).

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
...
std::rotate( std::begin(arr), std::end(arr)-1, std::end(arr));
arr[0] = new_int;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to use a `std::deque`. Then it becomes as simple as

```
my_deque.pop_back(); // get rid of last element.
my_deque.push_front(42); // put the new element at the front
```

Comment: Yup, this works fine and I dont need to use arrays. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vector` using `push` and `pop`. If you want to do it using arrays then you can:

```
int arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10};
int new_value = 20;

for(int i(0); i < 10 - 2; i++){
    arr[i + 1] ^= arr[i];
    arr[i] ^= arr[i + 1];
    arr[i + 1] ^= arr[i];
}
```

Or you can use a temporary variable instead of `XOR` operator:

```
    /*

    int tmp = arr[i + 1];
    arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = tmp;

    */

arr[0] = new_value;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    std::cout << arr[i] << ", ";
```

Comment: XOR swap is both less readable and, on modern machines with modern compilers, slower than a "regular" swap with temporary variable (that gets recognized and compiled straight to CPU swap instructions). Most importantly, in C++ you normally just use `std::swap`, which is terser and clearer than both options.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<int> arr;

arr.insert(arr.begin(), newvalue);
arr.pop_back();
```

Comment: You should actually do it the other way around, if you do `insert`+`pop_back` `vector` may reallocate on `insert` for no good reason, as you are going to pop the last element out anyway; if instead you do `pop_back` *and then* insert, it's guaranteed that you have enough `capacity` for the `insert` to succeed without reallocations.